# How to use Weasyprint with AWS Lambda? (Django & Zappa)

Tags: django, aws-lambda, cairo, weasyprint, python-zappa

I have a simple Django app which has been pushed to AWS Lambda using Zappa.

This process has worked properly, with one exception : `cannot load library 'pango-1.0': pango-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'pango-1.0'`

I'm using Weasyprint to generate PDF files. Weasyprint needs Cairo and Pango.

I don't know how to get Pango to work on my AWS Lambda install.

What should I do to make it work ?

Comment: [Leandro Hernández Mira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10270970) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67101433) saying "A probable solution is mentioned here [https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1690#issuecomment-606671178](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1690#issuecomment-606671178)"

Answer (score 2):

So, after asking around in multiple locations, I found out that I needed the static versions of all the libraries required by Weasyprint, and that I needed to push these in my zappa package.

Luckily, a github user has uploaded a working repo of the static requirements : https://github.com/Prasengupta/weasyprint_for_awslambda

So all I had to do was download it and extract all the folders at the root of my django app (the folders must be at the same level as the zappa_settings.json file).

I then just had to do a zappa update command to upload all these files to my AWS Lambda install, and it worked!

My Django app is now full of weird directories, but at least the whole thing works.

Comment: did not work for me at all. and my root dir is a mess now!

Comment: This solution does not work for python3.6 runtimes. *For now*

Comment: @AnnShress any specific reason why ?

Comment: @Brachamul https://github.com/Prasengupta/weasyprint_for_awslambda/issues/3#issuecomment-477301616